# SwiftPM warning about dependency conflicts when working on a local package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am the author and maintainer of the Swift package [Saga](https://github.com/loopwerk/Saga), which comes with an example app. Since pretty recently I am getting two warnings in Xcode about the way the dependencies are set up, and I am not sure how to solve this. The warnings:

`'sagaswimrenderer' dependency on 'https://github.com/loopwerk/Saga.git' conflicts with dependency on '/Users/kevin/Workspace/Saga/Saga' which has the same identity 'saga'. this will be escalated to an error in future versions of SwiftPM.`

`'sagaparsleymarkdownreader' dependency on 'https://github.com/loopwerk/Saga.git' conflicts with dependency on '/Users/kevin/Workspace/Saga/Saga' which has the same identity 'saga'. this will be escalated to an error in future versions of SwiftPM.`

This is the `Package.swift` file for the example app:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "Example",
  platforms: [
    .macOS(.v12)
  ],
  dependencies: [
    .package(path: "../"),
    .package(url: "https://github.com/loopwerk/SagaParsleyMarkdownReader", from: "0.5.0"),
    .package(url: "https://github.com/loopwerk/SagaSwimRenderer", from: "0.6.1"),
  ],
  targets: [
    .executableTarget(
      name: "Example",
      dependencies: [
        "Saga",
        "SagaParsleyMarkdownReader",
        "SagaSwimRenderer"
      ]
    ),
  ]
)
```

So it depends on the local version of Saga, and on actual released versions of SagaParsleyMarkdownReader and SagaSwimRenderer. But those two packages also depend on Saga, and that's what's causing the warnings.

I don't know how else to set up the example app so I don't get these warnings. I could rely on the released version of Saga, but that makes local development a LOT harder (I use the example app to work on features and bugfixes in Saga). SagaParsleyMarkdownReader and SagaSwimRenderer simply have to depend on Saga as they use code defined within Saga.

This used to work without warnings, and it continues to function just fine, but since the warnings says this will become an error in a future version of SwiftPM I need to find a solution.

Comment: Upvoted to help you get visibility. This is an important issue to stay ahead of! I found an unanswered question here as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701575

Comment: Historically I've had really bad luck getting answers on the Apple forums, but yeah not much better on StackOverflow with this question :(

Comment: I'll come back to this and let you know if I find out anything. I have many local packages but am only getting the warning for two of them.

Comment: Rather than doing ".package(path: "../")"  can you not use the url of the actual version, and then drag the local version in while you're working on it? That's how we do local development and Xcode is smart enough to use the local version instead of the remote version if they're named the same, and you'll see the remote one disappear. Then, when you're done, right-click, delete, and remove reference on the local one? My bad if I'm misunderstanding and this isn't what you want to do.